# Libcurl error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, libcurl, ios-3.x

im tryin to upgrade icy to iOS3/4+ but when im building it, it gives me this error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory how can i make this to work? i've read about adding cURL in the frameworks but i already did that and it gives me the same error... please help!

Comment: Your *search directory* project settings are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set path to your `curl` headers in the `Header Search Paths` section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your IDE's build settings you should find a **Header Search Paths** setting (or something similarly named). If you're building from the command-line, look for a **search path** option. Add the directory where curl.h resides to that list.